# Suspicious Whonix Gateway SSH connection

Tags: man-in-the-middle

I downloaded Whonix xfce-16.0.3.1 QEMU/KVM checked the integrity sha256 and installed it in Devian ASCII. Changed user and passwd. When starting the Gateway only an SSH connection takes place to the ip 146.57.248.255 (umn.edu) from local ip 10.0.2.15 and is returned to 10.233.11.41 this seen via etherape as below. I re downloaded the image re check the integrity and reinstalled and still a constant SSH connection on startup as above? Is it normal for the Whonix Gateway to permanently making a connection to this ip address? [image: etherape]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not normal. Unless that IP was a Tor relay or bridge at the time. You can use https://metrics.torproject.org/ and/or https://metrics.torproject.org/exonerator.html to find out which IPs have been in past or are now Tor relays.

That IP wasn't a Tor relay by the time you posted this question but better if you double-check that.

That screenshot is showing lots of IPs. For a clean issue reproduction, you would have to terminate all applications that connect to the internet. That is to have as few open connections to as few IPs as possible. Ideally zero. Or alternatively, you would need to have a good understanding which applications are connecting to which IPs, so you can exclude them from your observation.

Once starting Whonix, it should only be connecting either the the public Tor network (which IPs you can verify using the websites mentioned above) or to Tor bridges that you configured.

This is unlikely being a backdoor in Whonix because in that case it would make much more sense for Whonix to do what it is known for, that is only generating Tor traffic. Any malicious SSH connection would be much better hidden when routed through the Tor network together with all other traffic.

---

etherape seems to do a simple mapping from ports to a protocol.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports

Most web servers use port 80 for http, port 443 for https, port 22 for SSH. But there is no obligation to use these ports. Many people choose to run SSH on a non-standard port.

etherape showing "SSH" doesn't mean it has identified SSH traffic. At least not according to its description on its homepage. It is possible to detect the protocol (such as http, https, ssh) using DPI (deep package inspection) but etherrape does not claim to perform DPI.

Many Tor relays are using port 443. And these are not https web servers. Or port 9100 which doesn't have anything to do with Tor.

So in conclusion, etherape showing SSH doesn't mean it is a SSH connection.

---

Full disclosure:
I am a developer of Whonix.